# How to upload image file in Xamarin forms using rest api . Have issues with large images

Tags: forms, image, xamarin, upload

I tried and I face a problem when uploading images greater than 570 kb. This issue is in Xamarin Forms for android and PHP rest api. I tested the rest api separately and I have no issues there uploading 2mb files using postman.
Tried various ways also by giving some delay. I am capturing image using cross.media plugin. Then navigating to another page to upload. I wait for sometime  and then click the button to upload. I am not able ascertain where the issue is.

```
System.IO.Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
byte[] data = ReadFully(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();
MultipartFormDataContent multi = new MultipartFormDataContent();
ByteArrayContent imageStream = new ByteArrayContent(data);
StringContent SequenceID = new StringContent(osequence);
imageStream.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
imageStream.Headers.ContentDisposition = new           ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
 FileName = osequence, // "screenshot.jpg",   // generate this and send 
 Name = "avatar",
 };
 multi.Add(imageStream);
 alertLabel.Text = "Uploading Now";
 var response = await App.client.PostAsync(url, multi);
 string responsestr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 var retresponse = new retResponse();
 bool uploadSuccess = false;
```

I have made the rest api to send response on error and showing the same in an alert box as below

```
if (responsestr != "") alertLabel.Text = responsestr.ToString();
 else alertLabel.Text = alertLabel.Text + " After Upload Command ";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

} // private void upload(MediaFile mediaFile)
```

The error I get is no file sent

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore the above question. The problem was solved by changing the PHP.ini max upload file size. The file size in the device was around 500 - 700 KB . don't know how it comes to 1.99 and 2 mb when uploaded. Increasing max file size solved it.